# Dynamically populate other select option, but I want it display in same parent class only

Tags: jquery, ajax

I Have form like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get" name="gizi">
<div class="par1">
  <select name="jenis" class="jenis">
    <option selected="selected">--Merk--</option>
    <option value="1">Toyota</option>
    <option value="2">Nissan</option>
    <option value="3">Honda</option>

  </select>
  <select name="bahan" class="bahan">
    <option selected="selected">--Car name--</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="par2">
  <select name="jenis" class="jenis">
    <option selected="selected">--Merk--</option>
    <option value="1">Toyota</option>
    <option value="2">Nissan</option>
    <option value="3">Honda</option>
  </select>
  <select name="bahan" class="bahan">
    <option selected="selected">--Car name--</option>
  </select>
</div>

</form>
```

My Script looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".jenis").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'jenis=' + id;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_menu.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $(".bahan").html(html);
                }
            });

        });
            });
```

It works when I select an option in "--Merk--" , it  populate other select option in "----Car name----"
Example: I choose "Toyota", now ajax process it and display

```
<select name="bahan" class="bahan">
  <option value"1">Avanza</option>
  <option value"2">Kijang</option>
  <option value"3">Innova</option>
</select>
```

Now,.there is a problem here. Both ( class="bahan" in parent class="par1" ) and ( class="bahan" in parent class="par2") are populated/changed ...
I want  if I select option in class="par1" ,.. it only populated option in class="bahan" from parent class="par1", not both in par1 and par2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of targeting all `$(".bahan")` elements, you need to target the `bahan` which is the sibling of the changed `jenis` element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jenis").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'jenis=' + id;
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_menu.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $this.siblings(".bahan").html(html);
                //or $this.next().html(html);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".jenis").change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'jenis=' + id;
        var jenis = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_menu.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    jenis.siblings(".bahan").html(html);
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

used this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".jenis").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var dataString = 'jenis=' + id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_menu.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $(this).next(".bahan").html(html);
            }
        });

    });
```

});